# Harmonic Oscillators: Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

The book being used for this course is *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos* by Morris W. Hirsch.

The question is as follows.

> Suppose there are two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ attached to springs and walls. The springs connecting $m_j$ to the walls both have spring constants $k_1$, while the springs connecting $m_1$ and $m_2$ has spring constant $k_2$. This coupling means that the motion of either mass affects the behavior of the other.
>
> Let $x_j$ denote the displacement of each mass from its rest position, and assume that both masses are equal to 1. The differential equation for these coupled oscillators are then given by
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> x_1^{"}& = & -(k_1+k_2)x_1+k_2x_2\\
> x_2^{"}& = & k_2x_1-(k_1+k_2)x_2\\
> \end{eqnarray}
>
> - Write these equations as a first-order linear system.
> - Determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the corresponding matrix.
> - Find the general solution.
> - Let $\omega_1= \sqrt{k_1}$ and $\omega_2=\sqrt{k_1+2k_2}$. What can be said about the periodicity  of solutions relative to the $\omega_j$? Prove this.

Now I just want to focus on the first part: to see if my linear system is correct. I first start by introducing the new variable $y_j=x^{'}_j$ for $j = 1,2$, so that the equations can be written as a system. 
\begin{eqnarray}
x^{'}_1 & =& y_1\\
y^{'}_1 & =& -(k_1+k_2)x_1+k_2x_2\\
x^{'}_2 & =& y_2\\
y^{'}_2 & =& k_2x_1-(k_1+k_2)x_2 
\end{eqnarray}
In matrix form, this system is $X^{'}=AX$ where $X=(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)$ and 
\begin{align}
A & = & \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1&0 &0 \\
-(k_1+k_2)& 0& k_2& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1\\
k_2& 0& -(k_1+k_2)&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Do I have the right linear system?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your linear system is correct.  When in doubt, multiply it out row-by-row. For example, the first row reads

$$
x_1^\prime = [0, 1, 0, 0]\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\y_1\\x_2\\y_2 \end{array}\right] = y_1
$$Which is correct, by your definition of $y_1$.  The second row reads

$$
x_1^{\prime\prime} = y_1^\prime = [-(k_1+k_2), 0, k_2, 0]\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1\\y_1\\x_2\\y_2 \end{array}\right] = -(k_1+k_2)x_1 + k_2x_2
$$ which is the first of your original equations.  Do this for rows 3 and 4 to finish checking your answer.